# RN codepush Error : No variants found for ':react-native-code-push'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists. at (android)

Tags: react-native, code-push

#### Problems

After fully setting up CodePush, a build error occurs during the Android build process.
Works fine on IOS.

#### Tried behaviors

I had a similar issue and tried but failed.
Tried reordering the code

[github issues](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/1873)

#### Probable Cause

#### My code

```
settings.gradle file

rootProject.name = 'XXXX'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':react-native-twitter-signin'
project(':react-native-twitter-signin').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-twitter-signin/android')
include ':react-native-splash-screen'
project(':react-native-splash-screen').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/android')

include ':app', ':react-native-code-push'
project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app')
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')
```

```
MainApplication.java

private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
            new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
                @Override
                public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
                    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
                }

                @Override
                protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
                    List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
                    // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
                    // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
//                    packages.add(new SplashScreenReactPackage());
                    return packages;
//                    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
//                            new MainReactPackage(),
//                            new SplashScreenReactPackage()  //here
//                    );
                }


                @Override
                protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
                    return "index";
                }

                @Override
                protected boolean isNewArchEnabled() {
                    return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
                }

                @Override
                protected Boolean isHermesEnabled() {
                    return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
                }

                @Override
                protected String getJSBundleFile() {
                    return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
                }
            };

    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }
```

#### Error Message

```
No variants found for ':react-native-code-push'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists. at:
com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidModule.prepare(GradleModules.kt:266)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SyncProjectActionWorker.populateAndroidModels(SyncProjectActionWorker.kt:99)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:92)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderImpl.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:112)
  com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProvider.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:50)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:400)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:145)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:104)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.fromBuildModel(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:84)
  org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:57)
  org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$1(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:82)
  org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:106)
  org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$5(StateTransitionController.java:166)
  org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
  org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:166)
  org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
  org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:166)
  org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:103)
  org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:74)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:136)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
  org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
  org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
  org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
  org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
  org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
  org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
  org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
  org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
  org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:52)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:40)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
  org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
  org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
  org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
  org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
  java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
  java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

#### Environment

- react-native-code-push version: 8.0.1
- react-native version: 0.71.10
- iOS/Android/Windows version: android SDK 33 13(tiramisu)
- Does this reproduce on a debug build or release build? YES
- Does this reproduce on a simulator, or only on a physical device? No to both

(The more info the faster we will be able to address it!)

### Geeks, please help. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because your Android build configuration is not setting up the React Native Code Push module correctly.

Based on the error message and your build files, it seems the issue is that you are not properly including the Code Push module in your Android settings.gradle file. You have:

```
include ':app', ':react-native-code-push' 
project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new    File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app')
```

However, this is including the Code Push module at the wrong path. It should be:

```
include ':app', ':react-native-code-push'
project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new     File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android')enter code here
```

Notice the difference is `/android/app` vs `/android`.

You'll also want to ensure you have the Code Push module listed in your `getPackages()` method in your MainApplication.java file.

So in summary, the fixes are:

1. Update the Code Push path in settings.gradle to:

   project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android')
2. Add Code Push to the list of packages in `getPackages()` in MainApplication.java:

   java
   @Override
   protected List getPackages() {
   return Arrays.asList(
   new  CodePush(getResources().getString(R.string.reactNativeCodePush_androidDeploymentKey), getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.DEBUG),
   // other packages here
   );
   }

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm close to the answer, but I'm getting an error message like the GitHub issue I posted along with this one
I tried everything in the GitHub issue, but nothing worked.

Comment: No matching configuration of project :react-native-code-push was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.1' but